# Validate numeric input ONBLUR

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

There are a lot of posts about validating that only numeric numbers can be put in an input box. My request is a tad different. I am using a jquery plugin that allows someone to start typing in the input box and it pulls from a database. The result once I click an entry is a number. So, I need to be able to type in alphanumeric characters, but when I switch to another input box, at that time it should validate that the input box is numeric and if not, blank it out or something.

I have tried this:

```
     <script type="text/javascript">
 function isNumberKey(evt){
var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode
if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57))
    return false;
return true;
  }</script>
```

and the html part:

```
     onblur="return isNumberKey(event);"
```

When I do onkeypress, I can't enter alphanumeric like I said I needed to. When I do onblur, it allows me to enter alphanumeric BUT when I switch to another field, it doesn't blank out the line and allows me to proceed.

Comment: Please don't use intrusive event handlers...

Comment: Can you offer something else to use? Thanks

Comment: `$('input').on('blur', function(e) {  });` for example.

Comment: You could use jQuery method: `$.isNumeric()`  e.g: `$('input').on('blur', function() { if(!$.isNumeric(this.value)) this.value=""; });`

Answer (score 0):

Where you have `return false;` you should do something like `this.value = "";`.  What you have right now is not clearing anything.